# Add Class to select element on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this problem, I can't find the way to add class attribute in this Dropdown box

```
{{Form::select('bancada', Bancada::lists('nombre','idBancada'))}}
```

I have tried various syntax, but can not get it to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Use the forth parameter to add attributes to your element.

```
{{Form::select('bancada', Bancada::lists('nombre','idBancada'), null, ['class' => 'my_class'])}}
```

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L393) (`$options` is the same as attributes for your element).

Answer (score 9):

```
{{ Form::select('status', $statusList, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

In above example you can add class as fourth parameter