# Laravel 4 Form Select: apply a conditional class

Tags: php, laravel, select

```
{{ Form
.select('foo', {
    'foo': 'bar',
}) }}
```

I need to apply a class based on condition. For example I have an abstract `error` function that returns `bool`

How do I apply it like `'class' => 'error() ? 'my_class' : 'other_class'` ?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530975/laravel-4-blade-drop-down-list-class-attribute), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831509/add-class-to-select-element-on-laravel) <- no success

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 4:

```
{{ Form::select('name', ['value' => 'Label', 'another-value => 'Label'], null, ['class' => error() ? 'class' : 'another-class']) }}
```

In Laravel 5:

```
{!! Form::select('name', ['value' => 'Label', 'another-value => 'Label'], null, ['class' => error() ? 'class' : 'another-class']) !!}
```